# Using cascade correlated neural networks (retraining)

Tags: c++, matlab, neural-network

I have a problem that I would like to solve using neural networks. I have a basic understanding of how cascade correlated networks work, but I am not sure if I can use them in an example without complete retraining.

For example say I want to train a XOR example, but I only have the first three triplets of inputs/outputs:

- 0 0 0
- 0 1 1
- 1 0 1

I understand how to train the network for these inputs/outputs, but say I want to add a fourth triplet:

- 1 1 0

**without completely retraining** the whole network. If I understand the algorithm correctly it should be possible, but I haven't found an appropriate C++ library or MATLAB toolbox that implements this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any implementations, but people have made online versions of cascade correlation - which means constantly updating the network with new training data as it comes in, rather than training once on a static dataset.

I'm not sure how that works. I believe they just add new neurons every so often. You could also backprop through the whole thing like it was a normal neural network.

Comment: Thank you very much! I wasn't aware that this type of process is called "online". Could you please point me to any of these online cascade correlation versions?